# estimate a probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convolution, uniform-distribution, independence

Let $X_1....X_{48}$ be independent random variables, each follows a uniform probability
distribution over [0,1]. What is the best way to estimate P($\Sigma_{i=1}^{48} X_i > 20)$?

Comment: Have you considered using CLT?

Comment: I'm confused by the title, which might mean to estimate the "iid", vs. the body of the Question, which supposes the distribution is uniform on $[0,1]$.  An exact value can be computed, but you are perhaps interested in an estimate based on normal approximations?  Thus the phrase "best way" is perhaps worth clarifying.

Comment: [Chernoff or Hoeffding bounds](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~rocco/Teaching/S14/Readings/chernoffbounds.pdf) to give an upper bound on $\mathbb{P}\{\sum_{i=1}^{48} X_i \leq 20\}$ may be a good start. (I.e., an upper bound on the probability that the sum of $48$ i.i.d. r.v. variables in $[0,1]$ deviates from its mean by at least $4$.)

Comment: @ Alex, why CLT?! we have just 48 r.v!

Comment: (After back-of-the-envelope calculations, 48 seems to be too small for Hoeffding or Chernoff, the bounds get rather loose. But depending on what you are allowed to use... [Mathematica does have a Bates distribution.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Probability%5BX+%3E+20%2F48,+X~+BatesDistribution%5B48,+%7B0,+1%7D%5D%5D&t=crmtb01)

Comment: @ hard math.. you are right I changed the title... for the estimation doesn't matter normal or not

Comment: 48 isn't that small here. The Berry Esseen bounds you get are around 0.0009. See here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30468/error-in-normal-approximation-to-a-uniform-sum-distribution

Plus after normalization your right hand side is $(20-24)/(\sqrt(1/12)*48)=-0.29$, which is well away from either tail of the normal distribution.

Comment: 48 is usually more than big enough for CLT.

Comment: For those who considered CLT, can you elaborate, please?

Comment: @Klaus82 Done. See my answer. If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distribution of $ X_i$ and the normal distribution are both symmetric about the mean, which is an advantage if the Central Limit theorem (CLT) is applied. And the required condition of $n>30$ (rule of thumb) is fullfilled. We can use both distributions  and see if the approximation is good enough.

- Using Irwin–Hall distribution

$$1-P\left( \sum_{i=0}^{48}X_i\leq 20\right) =1 - \frac{1}{48!} \sum_{k=0}^{20} (-1)^k *{48 \choose k }*(20-k)^{48}=0.977364\approx 97.74\%$$

- Using the normal distribution as an approximation (CLT)

$$1-P\left( \sum_{i=0}^{48}X_i\leq 20 \right) \approx 1-\Phi\left( \frac{20-\mu}{\sigma} \right)$$

$=1-\Phi\left( \frac{20-24}{\sqrt{\frac{48}{12}}} \right)$

$=1-\Phi(-2)=1-0.02275=0.97725\approx 97.73\%$

As it is expected the approximation is good enough for the most purposes.

Comment: I think i=48 (the upper limit of Sigma)

Comment: @Klaus Sure. Thanks for the hint. I fixed it.

Comment: As a one-liner in _Mathematica_: `Probability[y > 20, y \[Distributed] UniformSumDistribution[48]]`  returns the exact answer which is approximately 0.977364 (as stated above)

Comment: something else, for CLT, why you didnt multiply $\mu$ by n? is it $\frac{20-n \mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$ ?

Comment: @Klaus82 The mean of a uniform random variable on $(0.1)$ is 0.5. You have 48 random variables. Thus $n\cdot \mu=48\cdot 0,5=24$. The variance of a uniform variable on $(0,1)$ is $\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}=\frac{(1-0)^2}{12}=\frac{1}{12}$. Therefore$ Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^{48} X_i\right) =n\cdot Var(X_i)=48\cdot \frac{1}{12}$.  The short resumee is: Yes I have multiplied by $n$.

Comment: sorrrrry my bad :)

Comment: @Klaus82 No problem.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of iid uniform random variables is an [Irwin-Hall distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) random variable:

$$P(\sum_{i=1}^{48} X_i > 20) = 1 - P(\sum_{i=1}^{48} X_i \le 20)$$

$$= 1 - \frac{1}{48!} \sum_{k=0}^{20} (-1)^k \binom{48}{k}(20-k)^{48}$$

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for approximation..nice job though!

Comment: You don't need an approximation, if you can get the exact answer

Comment: @Klaus82 an exact answer is the best approximation :P